# PHP convert text timezome to abbreviated ? like 'America/New_York' to 'EST'

Tags: php, timezone

so i have timezone in my DB in text format - is there a way to easily display is as the 3 character form ?

Comment: [Have a look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+convert+text+timezome+to+abbreviated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php you can do it like this

```
<?php
    $timezoneText = 'Pacific Standard Time'; // or whatever you have
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone($timezoneText);
    $currentTime = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
    $abbreviation = $currentTime->format('T');
    echo $abbreviation;
?>
```

Comment: works pretty much perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Make sure that you set the date and time of the DateTime object to the the date/time that you're targeting, otherwise you might wind up with PST instead of PDT, or vice-versa.